# Running shell command in background without waiting

Tags: python, shell, operating-system

I would like to run multiple commands concurrently in my python but the program seems to execute a command when the previous one is finished,

here is my code :

```
import os
import glob
for i in (glob.glob("PATH/SUB/*.csv")):
    file = i.split('\\')[1]
os.system("scrapy crawl quotes -a file=%s -o /OUTPUT/%s.csv &" % (file,file))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import glob
import asyncio


async def run(shell_command):
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(shell_command)
    await p.communicate()


async def main(shell_commands):
    for f in asyncio.as_completed([run(c) for c in shell_commands]):
        await f


commands = []
for i in (glob.glob("PATH/SUB/*.csv")):
    file = i.split('\\')[1]
    commands.append("scrapy crawl quotes -a file=%s -o /OUTPUT/%s.csv &" % (file, file))

loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop() 
loop.run_until_complete(main(commands))
loop.close()
```

#### Long answer:

You may check asyncio subprocess.

Let's test it. We will try to run 5 times "sleep 5" command - we expect total run time will be similar to 5 seconds (not 25 seconds).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import time
import asyncio
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT


async def run(shell_command):
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(shell_command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    return (await p.communicate())[0].splitlines()


async def main():
    commands = [run('sleep 5; echo {i}'.format(i=i)) for i in range(5)]
    for f in asyncio.as_completed(commands):
        print(await f)


start = time.time()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()

total = time.time() - start

print("Total time {} s".format(total))
```

Output:

```
[b'2']
[b'3']
[b'4']
[b'1']
[b'0']
Total time 5.0065038204193115 s
```

Everything as expected.

After adjusting to your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import glob
import asyncio


async def run(shell_command):
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(shell_command)
    await p.communicate()


async def main(shell_commands):
    for f in asyncio.as_completed([run(c) for c in shell_commands]):
        await f


commands = []
for i in (glob.glob("PATH/SUB/*.csv")):
    file = i.split('\\')[1]
    commands.append("scrapy crawl quotes -a file=%s -o /OUTPUT/%s.csv &" % (file, file))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(commands))
loop.close()
```

And finally, if you are using Windows, you need change

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

into

```
loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
```

And I assume you are using Windows because your code

```
file = i.split('\\')[1].
```